# Show that $\Bbb Z_p[i]$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_p[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, finite-fields, finite-rings

> Let $p$ be a prime number.  Show that $\Bbb Z_p[i]$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_p[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$.

My attempt:

Define 
 $$\phi : \Bbb Z_p[x] \to \Bbb Z_p[i]$$
by $\phi\big(f(x)\big)=f(i)$.  Then, it is trivial to show $\phi$ is well defined, homomorphism and onto.

So, I try to show $\ker\phi=\langle x^2+1\rangle$.  For given $f(x) \in \ker\phi$ , $f(i)=0$.  Then $f(x)$ has quadratic factor $x^2+1$ such that $f(x)=(x^2+1)h(x)$ for some $h(x) \in \Bbb Z_p[x]$.  It means that $f$ is in $\langle x^2+1\rangle $.

The other way is trivial to show by definition of principal ideal.  Thus, I can conclude $\Bbb Z_p[i]$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_p[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle $ by the First Isomorphism Theorem.

First, I know $\Bbb Z_p[i]$ is not even an integral domain for $p=5$. So, I want to know which part of above proof is wrong. I'll wait for your comment. Thank you!

Second, by similar way, I can approach to prove  that $\Bbb Z_p[\sqrt k]$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_p[x]/\langle x^2-k\rangle$, where $p$ is prime here and $k$ is not square number.  Is this right?

Comment: Sorry, why is $\mathbb{Z}_5 [i]$ not being an integral domain a problem? The isomorphism is to $\mathbb{Z}_5 [x] / \langle x^2 +1 \rangle$, which is not an integral domain either. For example, since $x^2 +1 = x^2 - 4 = \left(x+2\right)\left(x-2\right)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5 [x]$, we get two obvious zero-divisors...

Comment: How do you multiply $i by a congruence class?

Comment: Aha, I made a big mistake. $x^2+1$ is not irreducible in $Z_5[x]$

Comment: I've edited the question to improve formatting, replacing `<` and `>` with `$\langle$` and `$\rangle$` respectively and changing $\;ker\;$ to $\;\text{ker}$. Do you approve the changes that I made in the edit? My intentions were to improve the formatting in the question. Do you believe I have successfully done this? $(+1)$ by the way (and in case you were wondering, I won't take back the upvote even if you disapprove of my edit) :P

Comment: @user477343 Thank you for edit. I learn new function to notate this symbol!

Comment: You may want to share your definition of $\Bbb{Z}_p[i]$ with us. Does it mean the quotient ring $\Bbb{Z}[i]/\langle p\rangle$ of the ring of Gaussian integers $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ modulo the principal ideal generate by $p$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Oh, My definition of $Z_p[i]=\{a+bi|a,b\in \Bbb Z_p\}$ actually.

Comment: No problemo! Glad to help :D